# Excel VBA: Workbook Event on file that was open with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, events

I am trying to do the following thing- I open a new worksheet with Worksheet.Open method and then on double-click in this open file copy the active tab to the initial spreadsheet. I have no clue on how to do the coping part, can it be done via Workbook Event?

Lukasz

Comment: Can you please show the code you already have...

Comment: As I have written I have no clue how to do it. I have written a code that opens a workbook and copies a range from a predefined sheet. I wanted to make it more flexible to address a situation when sheet name is change (or order)                                                                                                                                                    My code is basically a  loop that goes through a range with files location, opens each and copies a range. how do I copy the code here? it says it is too long